# Error '9' en tiempo de ejecución al abrir Archivos y hojas de cálculo

Tags: excel, vba

Cordial saludo equipo, espero se encuentren bien quiero agradecer su colaboración que se me presenta con un inconveniente que se me presenta respecto a utilizar las instrucciones WorkBook y WorkSheets en Excel VBA:

Tengo un libro dentro de la misma carpeta, con nombre datasets.xls, el cual tiene una hoja con nombre iris:

Mediante el siguiente código de programación deseo abrir el archivo o libro mencionado, con nombre datasets.xls y la hoja con nombre  iris:

```
Sub Rectángulo7_Haga_clic_en()
  Workbooks("datasets.xls").WorkSheets("iris").Activate
End Sub
```

Al ejecutar el código me muestra el siguiente error:

> Se ha producido el error '9' en tiempo de ejecución:
> SubIndice fuera del intervalo

He investigado por mi parte y la solución al problema que me muestran es que el error radica en que no se encuentra el archivo o como si estuviera
trabajando con posiciones en un array, en ese orden de ideas no veo relación en las ayudas que he encontrado con lo que tengo para solucionar  el problema mencionado.

Muchas gracias de antemano por la colaboración que me puedan brindar

Comment: Para abrir un archivo Excel desde otro archivo Excel tienes que usar la instrucción `Application.Workbooks.Open` https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open . Tu código lo que hace es activar la hoja Iris del libro dataset, pero como no este archivo no está abierto, da error 9 (fuera del intervalo de libros abiertos). Primero ábrelo y luego podrás ejecutar tu comando.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si le das la ruta absoluta al archivo datasets? Cómo estás ejecutando este código que nos muestras?

Answer (score 1):

tienes la extension a "xls", version vieja del excel.
la extension del archivo tal ves es xlsx? incluso si tiene macros la extension es "xlsm" y por eso no lo encuentra
yo normalmente primero pido los nombres de los archivos a trabajar con getopenfilename para evitar ese error de versiones del excel.
espero te sirva esta informacion jejeje